# call UITableView methods from UITouch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitouch

I have a table with customs cells, which has subclass `UITableViewCells` and for control touches I use `UITouch` (code based on this tutorial http://gregprice.co.uk/blog/?p=280) I need inside `touchesEnded` method get index of cell which was touch.

I try:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   //some code

   UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)self.superview;
   NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath alloc];
   index = [parentTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
   NSLog(@"Call, x= %f, index=%d", xPos, index.row);

}
```

But always I've got index=0.

Whats I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you are taking a very round about way to select a row in a UITableView. set your UITableView's delegate and data source to the class you are working in, then implement its protocol methods which you can find in the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource reference. Once you have done that you can use this method to determine which row was selected in the table

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

maybe you already knew this but it sounds like you are new to iOS development and i dont see why you would want to manually do it that way.

and also as Dave Leverton's answer said, dont do an alloc like that

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is causing the problems but it's bad practice to call 'alloc' like you are here. I'd remove the line with alloc (As this is creating memory for an object you're not initialising or using) and just have the NSIndexPath object defined in-line:

```
UITableView *parentTable = (UITableView *)self.superview;
NSIndexPath *index = [parentTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSLog(@"Call, x= %f, index=%d", xPos, index.row);
```